# I can't handle object properties in google apps script

Tags: object, google-apps-script

I am trying to create objects in Google Apps Script and I can't handle their properties. In the code below I don't understand why my build function don't work then the manualy sets neither

```
var my_object = Object.create(null,{
    type:     {value:"abc", enumerable:true},
    name:     {value:"abc", enumerable:true},

    build: {
      value:function(my_type,my_name){
        this.type =     my_type;
        this.name =     my_name;
        return this;
      }
    }
  });

  var my_type = "my type";
  var my_new_object = Object.create(my_object).build(my_type, "my name");

  // In my_new_object I found the "abc" from definition but not the values from my_range and "my name"
  console.log(my_type);      
  console.log(my_new_object.type);
  console.log(my_new_object.name);

  // And I don't succeed to set directly the properties neither
  my_new_object.type = "my type";
  my_new_object.name = "my name";      
  console.log(my_new_object.type);
  console.log(my_new_object.name);

  // I always get the "abc" from object definition
```

Do I need special setters and getters to handle object properties?
Thanks!

Comment: Avoid phrases like "don't succeed", " doesn't work". Explain clearly with exact error message quotes, logs and what happens.

Comment: yes sorry it was just the introduction, messages are detailed in the code's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the writable properties to your object

```
  type:     {value:"abc", enumerable:true, writable: true},
  name:     {value:"abc", enumerable:true, writable: true},
```

I'm just curious, why not use the simplier approach?

```
function MyObject(type,name) {
  this.type = type;
  this.name = name;
}

var my_object = new MyObject("my_type","my_name");
```

Comment: perfect I succeed to set the properties, thank you !